# Angularjs tutorial step 7; not able to see a dynamically created list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi I'm  following the Angularjs tutorial and up to step 7 is where the tutorial stop working for me. My index.html just became blank and I have no idea why.

here's the codes
index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Google Phone Gallery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

 </head>
<body >
<div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

controller.js

```
 'use strict';

 /* Controllers */

var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
function PhoneListCtrl($scope, $http) {
$http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
  $scope.phones = data;
 });
 $scope.orderProp = 'age';
 }]);

 phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
 function($scope, $routeParams) {
 $scope.phoneId = $routeParams.phoneId;
}]);
```

app.js

```
 'use strict';

 /* App Module */

var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
 'ngRoute',
  'phonecatControllers'
 ]);

phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
  when('/phones', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
    controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
  }).
  when('/phones/:phoneId', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
    controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/phones'
  });
 }]);
```

phone-list.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span2">
  <!--Sidebar content-->

  Search: <input ng-model="query">
  Sort by:
 <select ng-model="orderProp">
    <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
    <option value="age">Newest</option>
  </select>

 </div>
 <div class="span10">
  <!--Body content-->

  <ul class="phones">
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp"  class="thumbnail">
      <a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}" class="thumb"><img ng-src="{{phone.imageUrl}}">  </a>
      <a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}">{{phone.name}}</a>
      <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
     </li>
     </ul>

    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

also here's the console errors I got but don't understand

```
  GET file:///C:/Users/John/Desktop/Angular-Family/app/lib/angular/angular-  route.js  index.html:9
  Uncaught ReferenceError: phonecatControllers is not defined controllers.js:7
  Uncaught Error: No module: ngRoute
```

any ideas?

EDIT2:

```
  Failed to load resource file:///C:/Users/John/Desktop/Angular-Family/app/app.js
  Failed to load resource file:///C:/Users/John/Desktop/Angular- Family/app/controllers.js
 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module phonecatApp due to:
 Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'phonecatApp' is not available! You either misspelled     the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/$injector/nomod?p0=phonecatApp
 at http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-7/app/lib/angular/angular.js:78:12
 at http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-7/app/lib/angular/angular.js:1330:36
 at ensure (http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step- 7/app/lib/angular/angular.js:1268:38)
 at module (http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-7/app/lib/angular/angular.js:1328:14)
 at http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-7/app/lib/angular/angular.js:3071:26
 at Array.forEach (native)
 at forEach (http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step- 7/app/lib/angular/angular.js:224:11)
 at loadModules (http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-7/app/lib/angular/angular.js:3065:5)
at createInjector (http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-7/app/lib/angular/angular.js:3007:11)
at doBootstrap (http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-7/app/lib/angular/angular.js:1152:20)
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=phonecatApp&p1…2Fangular- phonecat%2Fstep-7%2Fapp%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1152%3A20) angular.js:3097
```

Comment: i think you need to specify the controller to main div controller as well. `<div class="container-fluid" data-ng-controller='PhoneListCtrl '>`

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the controllers on the `phonecatControllers` module. However that module is not defined. So when the angular app attempts to inject the module it is unable to find it.

Try changing the following line from this.

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);
```

to this

```
var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);
```

In addition to the that it appears angular is unable to load the `ngRoute` dependency as well. The script reference appears to be present. You may want to check and make sure `lib/angular/angular-route.js` is not returning a 404.

### Update**

I think the problem now is mismatched versions of angular and angular-route. There is a service that the route provider is looking for that is not available.

I was able to get it working using the same scripts from that tutorials demo.

[Working Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/HIe16FgdtdqOm8JwGQzA?p=preview)

```
<script src="http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-7/app/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-7/app/lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
```

This is by no means an ideal solution, but should help you keep moving forward with the tutorial. You could of course download the contents of these file to your local machine.

Comment: Did change to that but the list is still not working

Comment: Failed to load resource file:///C:/Users/John/Desktop/Angular-Family/app/lib/angular/angular-route.js
Uncaught Error: No module: ngRoute

Comment: @user2809321 It appears that the ngRoute module is also not being correctly injected. Are there any 404 errors when you load the page? Is the file lib/angular/angular-route.js being correctly served

Comment: Yea Failed to load resource file:///C:/Users/John/Desktop/Angular-Family/app/lib/angular/angular-route.js is kinda like a 404. Also be careful when working locally with Angular sometimes it breaks the AJAX, it's better to work from a web server.

Comment: Exactly as @NicolasMoise pointed out you may need to download that file separately. Does that file exist at the specified location? If not simply download it and add it to your project.

Comment: I posted the new errors I got when I added the angular-route.js

Comment: that's so weird its giving me another error. Plus I added that phone.json file if that helps. The error is posted up

Comment: It is still failing to load your scripts `Failed to load resource file:///C:/Users/John/Desktop/Angular-Family/app/app.js`
  `Failed to load resource file:///C:/Users/John/Desktop/Angular- Family/app/controllers.js`. You may want to try setting this up to be served from a webserver, IIS, Apache or Node.

Answer (score 0):

phonecatControllers.controller, change this to

phonecatApp.controller

good luck